# How do I add a HTML hash link without it altering the URL bar...?

Tags: html, hash, hyperlink, href, hashtag

When I add a HTML link to a specific part of the page:

```
<a href="#specific">test</a>
```

I noticed that it changes the URL at the address bar. Although I have come across websites where they link that way without the address bar being updated. How is this possible?

EDIT: It might be an AJAX solution were they make it work without URL change, as if I remember correctly, the page didn't reload, it went directly to the destination...

Comment: why not use javascript, e.g. `window.scrollTo()`?

Comment: I have no javascript knowledge. Could you please answer this with a working javascript example and I will be satisfied with that solution.

Comment: Hi Alehandro Darie, can you give a bit of background to why you don't want to alter the URL bar? Just so we can structure a answer for you. thanks.

Comment: @AlexKey thank you for the reply. The reason why is because if the visitor reloads the page OR bookmarks it, it will always go to the specific destination. The problem is that I have developed a one-page type of portfolio design and it is likely that the visitor will bookmark the site once browsing through the site, which means that when they will bookmark it and return to the site, they will land at a random part of the page (rather than the top). I hope that this makes any sense...

Comment: Cool, thanks Alehandro, just putting together a response for you now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may wish to look at the jquery plugin, scrollTo.

http://jquery.com

And a couple of links for scrollTo

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

You can do something like this:

**The HTML**

```
<a href="#scrollToMe" class="scrollLink">click me to scroll</a>
<div class="gap">a big gap</div>
<h1 id="scrollToMe">I should scroll to here without a # in the URL</h1>
```

**The javascript (jquery and the scrollto plugin)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scrollLink").click(function(e) {

        $.scrollTo($(this).attr("href"));    
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

What the javascript does, is when ever a link is clicked that has the class ".scrollLink", scroll the page down to the element that has the same ID, as the href for the particular link clicked. Then the e.preventDefault() stops it working like the normal hash link and stops it appearing in the URL bar.

Here is a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/c3jsY/7/

And a version not in a frameset, so you can see that the URL doesn't change:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/alexkey/c3jsY/7/show/light/

This approach has a couple of good points

1. Simply apply the scrollLink class to links you want to stop the hash appearing (nice and easy)
2. It uses the normal href, which also means the links will still work even if javascript is disabled - good for accessibility and probably search engine optimisation to.

Comment: Please to help @AlehandroDarie, glad to be of assistance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use javascript to intercept the click event, perform your own custom logic, then cancel the navigation event so the URL never changes

Comment: Could you kindly write me the code for this solution? Note that I have no javascript knowledge unfortunately, only rather basic HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like: window.scroll(0,150);
instead of "(0,150)" put the cooridnate of your target.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to experiment with the number (shown here as 200) to get the window to align properly.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.scroll(0,200);">test</a>
```

Comment: And if I will align it correctly, will the target be exactly the same on all browsers? As I mentioned earlier, I am not very experienced with javascript and therefore do not know under which rules it operates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline the next code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById(\'bookmark\').scrollIntoView();"> link text </a>
<div id="bookmark">Jump to here</div>
```