# Not using the url from a header redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using a header redirection to go back to a pagejump spot at my webpage. I did this with `header('Location: index.php#contact');`.

The problem I have now is that it says

> www.pagename/index.php#contact

The problem is that I don't want to see the #contact in my url, how can I fix this?

Btw, the page were I use `header('Location: index.php#contact');` is a different page as the one were I have the anchor.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to be any use to you, but check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272215/how-do-i-add-a-html-hash-link-without-it-altering-the-url-bar

Comment: No that doesn't help,  cause its not happening on the same page.

Comment: you need a JS solution to use a hashtag if you want it to go to that place in the file

Comment: at best; use a full http call. I.e.: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php#contact');`

Comment: `www.pagename` again, see ^

Comment: you also tagged as htaccess and mod-rewrite (edit: *"someone tagged htacces and mod-rewrite for me"* - Oh, I see). I'll delete this shortly.

Comment: If you want something special to happen on `index.php`, like jumping to a specific part of the page that it doesn't go to when you just visit `index.php` directly, then you need to include that information *somewhere* in the URL. There's no other secret backchannel where you could transport the information.

Comment: Ye I saw, someone tagged htacces and mod-rewrite for me. But I'm kinda new to this. Were can I find code for "mod-rewrite", and I am using phpstorm now (so it's not online yet) so I don't think I have a htacces file.

Comment: I also saw a jquery that filtered all #'s and names after the #'s out of the url and gave back the standard url everywere. But I can't find that tutorial anymore.

Comment: Well, what JustBaron posted seems correct to use. If you are indeed looking to use a mod rewrite, then that's a whole different ballgame.

Comment: @Minegolfer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606127/mod-rewrite-hash-tags that might be a better link.

Comment: I don't understand anything of that topic cause I never worked with that, but i'm gonna try to learn some of that stuff so thanks :)  This should be good enough

Comment: @Minegolfer you can keep Googling "mod rewrite htaccess", you'll get a lot more there and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you add some javascript code at [index.php] to change the URL. Like this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    history.pushState({},\"index.php#contact\",\"index.php\");
</script>";
```

The second parameter is the original URL, and the third parameter is the URL you want to display.

That's all.O(∩_∩)O~